# lag must be exactly 2weeks

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, scheduling, ms-project-2016

I have a number of tasks which have 3 subtasks each that MUST start and be completed exactly 2 weeks from each other. (each subtask is half day)
i.e. task1: (subtask1 @ day1, subtask2 @ day14, subtask3 @ day28)

The problem is that if I use lag, when I have many tasks (more than 200) and I level the resources, the subtasks2 of each task is pushed by the subtasks1 so they are scheduled more than 2 weeks from the linked subtask1)

I could use constraint but I need the tasks to float so if I change the starting day or the priority of the main tasks everything will be rescheduled maintaining a fixed 2 weeks delay of each subtask.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your lag values and then:

- Option 1: If it is resource levelling that is causing the subtasks to be moved around, then set up a "special" resource that is only used on those subtasks. This means there will never be resource overloading and so the subtasks are never moved by Levelling. Of course, this does lead to a potential overloading of the *actual* resource because MS-Project will see them as different resources and will assign them on the same day as it will see no overloading
- Option 2: Use Priorities. Set a higher priority on the subtasks than any other task where there could be a resource clash. Given they *must* occur on your strict timing, set them to the highest possible priority (999) and ensure that the 'Levelling Order' is 'Priority, Standard'. This means MS-Project will attempt to preserve their timing above all others and so the other clashing tasks, at a lower priority, will be moved first. This option would be my personal preference as there are no real downsides

Comment: Hi Marv, thank you fro your answer. I need to use leveling as the main tasks need to be scheduled by priority. It works of I use "level by ID", but if I do that, then I can level by priority. I use only one resource. Also if I level by priority or ID it will simply schedule the highest priority first but if there is a gap between high priority tasks it will put in there the first of the lower priority tasks and the second and third will be pushed at more than 2 weeks delay.

Comment: Ok I have tested, and I cannot find a way to push ST2 because of levelling effects from other tasks, though I am using a very simple project with few tasks. As far as I can tell ST2 would only be pushed if there was a higher priority task, which is why I suggested making all the subtasks the HIGHEST priority. I don't understand your comment- if you Level by ID then you cannot level by priority. I have linked a task and two subtasks using S-S relationship with lag of 10 days, Level by 'Priority, Standard' and 'Levelling can create splits...' and I cannot get them to move through levelling!

Comment: ok, let me explain better... look at the picture attached. http://postimg.org/image/tp7cffsjv/   Let's say my team has a capability of completing 3 subtasks per week. Each task has it's own priority, some tasks will have the same priority. There will be new tasks that will be added to the plan at any time and their priority might be higher than the one already scheduled. Priorities could also change and if they do schedule should be recalculated for the non started tasks.

Comment: Either your subtasks MUST start on time, and therefore *they* must have the highest priority, or incoming tasks have an even higher priority- you cannot have it both ways. Saying a task may not be pushed by a higher priority task means it is *not* a higher priority task! If you cannot work with it you have only two options- use a different resource *in the MSP* for the unmovable tasks so Levelling does not try to resolve a clash, or don't use Levelling...

Comment: Looking again, and thinking more about your needs, I am not sure Project is really the right tool for you. Project tries to actively manage and balance its list of tasks according to availability and priority. You *might* be able to force it to approximate what you need, by making ST1 a higher priority that ST2, and 2 higher than 3, all within a framework where Task1 (and its subtasks) are all higher priority than T2 and all *its* subtasks. But what's the point? By the time you have done that and tied it in knots you might as well do manual scheduling since you have removed all automation!

Comment: Obviously resources will change over the time and so will the priorities. The case I described to you is obviously an over simplification of what I need. There will be hundred of tasks and there will be trees of subtasks for each main task which won't make practical to do manual scheduling. Assigning a different priority to tasks and subtasks won't help as no matter what priority the task has, MSP will schedule the priority in the first available slot. The goal would be to make only the main task floating... is there any other software you can think of that might help me achieving what I need?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve then. I believe a combination of Lag and Priority will get you what you described, as long as the subtasks have a higher priority than the tasks around them. I can't help with any other software recommendations I am afraid.

Comment: [SOLVED] it's not the ideal solution that I was looking for but it works for me. I made the assumption that on average the sum of ST1,ST2 and ST3 is always the same. I assigned this average value as duration of ST1 and made ST2 and 3 zero duration. I created custom duration1, start1 and finish1. I linked the ST with SS relationship. start1=ProjDateAdd([Start],[Duration1]), finish1=ProjDateAdd([Start],[Duration1]+0.5), duration1, manually insered (10days for ST2 and 30days for ST3). I then modified the gantt chart bars to display start and finish1. I hope this will help someone else too

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the schedule leveling function.  You don't need it.